# Let font size determines parent's height in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is my sample code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/cloud_burst"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vwColor"

        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 

        android:background="#132123"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vwColor"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"

        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Age"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/fiord"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the parent view to enlarge or shrink according to the font size of children views, so I set parent's height and TextView to wrap_content. However, I can't make the View, in which I filled a color, fill parent's height. Seems this attribute is automatically set to zero. In other words, I want to set parent's and other elements' heights base on the height of TextView.

Of course there is a workaround: set the parent's background to the desired color, and change the background of TextView instead of View, but I want to do some experiments and need a better solution :v

So, how to fix this?

Comment: you can add one more relative layout and the text view should be inside that

Comment: no change @VV besides, I want to keep it as flat as possible :)

Comment: Use ```margin``` instead of ```padding```

Comment: didn't work... @DanhDC